# Persisting on screen indicators past a poll using ember data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-data

Been having some issues with an ember.js+emberdata program I'm building. A basic version of it is included below. The issue is, every five seconds I poll for changes to a value (price) and i turn the value red or green based on whether the price has gone up or down. Please note that in the actual issue i am showing a css animation, not just a css color change. Every time I reload the model this resets this value. How would I make it so that, for instance, the red/green color persists for seven seconds rather than just five? So if there is a price change, I would show green for seven seconds and ignore any changes that are made during the time of that color change. Feel free to ask for more details I may have left out. Also any constructive notes on the implementation are appreciated. Sample program and setup details follow:

## **Web app Side**

### test_ember_code.js

```
(function() {
  var App;

  App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_BINDINGS: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
    LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION: true,
    LOG_VERSION: true,
    debugMode: true
  });

  App.Router.map(function() {
    return this.resource("product");
  });

  App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
      this.transitionTo("product");
    }
  });

  App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    price: DS.attr('number', {
      "default": 1
    }),
    oldPrice: DS.attr('number', {
      "default": null
    }),
    storeOldPrice: function() {
      return this.set('oldPrice', this.get('price'));
    },
    priceChanged: (function() {
      if (this.get('oldPrice') != null) {
        return this.get('price') !== this.get('oldPrice');
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).property('price', 'oldPrice'),
    priceMovedUp: (function() {
      if (this.get('oldPrice') != null) {
        return this.get('price') > this.get('oldPrice');
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).property('price', 'oldPrice'),
    priceFormatted: (function() {
      if (this.get('price')) {
        return this.get('price').toFixed(2);
      }
    }).property('price', 'oldPrice'),
    oldPriceFormatted: (function() {
      if (this.get('oldPrice')) {
        return this.get('oldPrice').toFixed(2);
      } else {
        return 0.00;
      }
    }).property('oldPrice')
  });

  App.ProductAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken) {
      return this.ajax('http://localhost:3000', 'GET');
    }
  });

  App.ProductController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    backupPrices: function() {
      return this.get('model').filter(function(product) {
        return product.storeOldPrice();
      });
    }
  });

  App.ProductSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
      return this._super(store, type, payload);
    }
  });

  App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      console.log('model load');
      return this.store.findAll('product');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      console.log('setting up controller');
      this._super(controller, model);
      return Em.run.later(this, this.startPolling, 5000);
    },
    startPolling: function() {
      this.set('polling', true);
      return Em.run.later(this, this.refresh, 5000);
    },
    refresh: function() {
      if (!this.get('polling')) {
        return;
      }
      console.log('polling');
      this.controller.backupPrices();
      this.store.findAll('product');
      return Em.run.later(this, this.refresh, 5000);
    },
    actions: {
      willTransition: function() {
        return this.set('refreshing', false);
      }
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

### index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .up{
                background-color:green;
            }
            .down{
                background-color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
            <h1>Price Update Test</h1>
            {{outlet}}
        </script>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index"></script>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="product">
            {{#each}}
                <p>
                    Current Price:  
                    <span {{bind-attr class="priceChanged priceMovedUp:up:down"}}>
                        {{priceFormatted}}
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                    Old Price:
                    <span> 
                        {{oldPriceFormatted}}
                    </span>
                </p>
            {{/each}}
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember.prod.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js"></script>  
        <script src="test_ember_code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## **Node server Side**

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "priceChangeServer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Simple http service that returns a data to show a random number to simulate price changes",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.1"
  }
}
```

### server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  randomValue1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  randomValue2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  res.send('{"products":[{"id":1,"price":'+randomValue1+'},{"id":2,"price":'+randomValue2+'}]}');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

### How to run the webapp

Create the following folder structure

[image: layout for this app]

Enter the server_app folder and run 'npm install'. Then run 'node server.js' ( assuming you have installed node and properly configured. if not, you need to have in order to run this). It should say 'listening on *:3000'.

Next, go into the web_app folder and open index.html in your browser. Note: you may have to start your browser with web security disabled. Chrome will complain of CORS issues, since the server is running on localhost and the web app isn't. For chrome that's starting it with the --disable-web-security flag. eg: 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security' on windows.

You'll now see the Current price changing every five seconds, along with a color change based on whether it's red or green. That's the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code where you pull the new data from the model (Route) into the Controller.
Then the value will never go back to 0 and you will not get you're weird flickering issue.

Hope that helps :)